# Runtime Processors Calculation for the JVM in Kubernetes Containers

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, containers

I am running a JVM in a `K8s` pods, and I have allocated it `512m` of CPU and `1Gi` of memory. When we execute

In context of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`,

1. what would be the value returned? I want to know this since some of the libraries like Couchbase Java client, RxJava etc. rely on this value to determine the number of threads in various thread-pools.
2. How is the value `512m` interpreted. Would it take the floor or the ceil of this value? Or is there a different way to compute this altogether?

Comment: WHich version of Java are you using? For older versions, `availableProcessors()` always returns the number of CPUs or virtual CPUs your OS sees.

Comment: It's Java 8 I am using.

Comment: I think different updates handled it differently. If you have the latest it should be based on the number of CPUs the OS will allow the process to run on.